# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: graphql/schema/idl/ScalarInfo.STANDARD_SCALAR_DEFINITIONS

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, graphql, build.gradle

My application is not started because of the below issue. Please help me with this.

**My build.gradle file :**

```
    apply plugin: 'java-library'
    apply plugin: 'war'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'maven'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin'

    buildscript {
            ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.1-2'
        
            repositories {
                jcenter()
                mavenCentral()
            }
            dependencies {
                classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.0.1-2'
            }
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '2.3.3.RELEASE'
        compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.3.3.RELEASE'
        compile group: 'com.graphql-java-kickstart', name: 'graphql-spring-boot-starter', version: '7.2.0'
        compile group: 'com.graphql-java-kickstart', name: 'graphql-java-servlet', version: '10.0.0'
        compile group: 'com.graphql-java-kickstart', name: 'graphql-spring-boot-autoconfigure', version: '7.2.0'
        providedCompile group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.18.12'
        //implementation("com.graphql-java:graphql-java-extended-scalars:2020-02-19T04-04-26-6f82be9")
        compile group: 'org.mariadb.jdbc', name: 'mariadb-java-client', version: '2.6.2'
        compile group: 'com.graphql-java', name: 'graphql-java-extended-scalars', version: '1.0.1'
        //compile group: 'com.graphql-java-kickstart', name: 'graphql-java-tools', version: '5.6.1'
        compile group: 'com.graphql-java-kickstart', name: 'graphql-java-tools', version: '6.1.0'
        //compile group: 'com.graphql-java', name: 'graphql-java', version: '2020-10-16T05-33-59-df5bbde'
        compile group: 'com.graphql-java', name: 'graphql-java', version: '13.0'
        compile group: 'com.graphql-java-kickstart', name: 'playground-spring-boot-starter', version: '5.10.0'
        compile group: 'com.graphql-java-kickstart', name: 'voyager-spring-boot-starter', version: '7.2.0'
    }
```

**My Error Message**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'schemaParser' defined in class path resource [graphql/kickstart/tools/boot/GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [graphql.kickstart.tools.SchemaParser]: Factory method 'schemaParser' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: graphql/schema/idl/ScalarInfo.STANDARD_SCALAR_DEFINITIONS
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:635) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$157/0000000000000000.getObject(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) [spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) [spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at com.test.TestProjectApplication.main(TestProjectApplication.java:14) [bin/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [graphql.kickstart.tools.SchemaParser]: Factory method 'schemaParser' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: graphql/schema/idl/ScalarInfo.STANDARD_SCALAR_DEFINITIONS
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: graphql/schema/idl/ScalarInfo.STANDARD_SCALAR_DEFINITIONS
    at graphql.kickstart.tools.TypeClassMatcher.match(TypeClassMatcher.kt:83) ~[graphql-java-tools-6.1.0.jar:na]
    at graphql.kickstart.tools.TypeClassMatcher.match$default(TypeClassMatcher.kt:26) ~[graphql-java-tools-6.1.0.jar:na]
    at graphql.kickstart.tools.TypeClassMatcher.match(TypeClassMatcher.kt:74) ~[graphql-java-tools-6.1.0.jar:na]
    at graphql.kickstart.tools.TypeClassMatcher.match(TypeClassMatcher.kt:23) ~[graphql-java-tools-6.1.0.jar:na]
    at graphql.kickstart.tools.SchemaClassScanner.scanResolverInfoForPotentialMatches(SchemaClassScanner.kt:261) ~[graphql-java-tools-6.1.0.jar:na]
    at graphql.kickstart.tools.SchemaClassScanner.handleRootType(SchemaClassScanner.kt:114) ~[graphql-java-tools-6.1.0.jar:na]
    at graphql.kickstart.tools.SchemaClassScanner.scanForClasses(SchemaClassScanner.kt:72) ~[graphql-java-tools-6.1.0.jar:na]
    at graphql.kickstart.tools.SchemaParserBuilder.scan(SchemaParserBuilder.kt:154) ~[graphql-java-tools-6.1.0.jar:na]
    at graphql.kickstart.tools.SchemaParserBuilder.build(SchemaParserBuilder.kt:195) ~[graphql-java-tools-6.1.0.jar:na]
    at graphql.kickstart.tools.boot.GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration.schemaParser(GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration.java:151) ~[graphql-kickstart-spring-boot-autoconfigure-tools-7.2.0.jar:na]
    at graphql.kickstart.tools.boot.GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e5e64929.CGLIB$schemaParser$2(<generated>) ~[graphql-kickstart-spring-boot-autoconfigure-tools-7.2.0.jar:na]
    at graphql.kickstart.tools.boot.GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e5e64929$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$cb005481.invoke(<generated>) ~[graphql-kickstart-spring-boot-autoconfigure-tools-7.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at graphql.kickstart.tools.boot.GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e5e64929.schemaParser(<generated>) ~[graphql-kickstart-spring-boot-autoconfigure-tools-7.2.0.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

Comment: It looks like Spring Boot is expecting a different version of the GraphQL library than you have specified in your dependencies. You might want to consider using the Spring Boot BOM and not specify versions of dependencies that are defined in the Spring Boot BOM.

Comment: I am facing same error, what steps did you take to resolve it @AyyasamyS